# identifying vertex in graph

Tags: graph-theory

I need help understanding this [Lemma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkT6p.png)
and proof.

**Lemma**
Let $G$ be the graph obtained from a graph $G_1$ by identifying an arbitrary vertex of $G_1$ and one pendent vertex of the path $P_2.$
 Then the determinant of the distance matrix of the graph $G$ is fixed, regardless the
  choice of the vertex of $G.$

Does $P_2$ mean chordless path on $2$ vertices?
Does identifying vertices mean contracting them in one vertex which has edges to 
all vertices that these two had? How is it possible that then $G_1$ is subgraph of $G$ when $G$ was obtained from $G_1$ by identifying vertices?

Comment: What is $P_2$? and what is the definition of a "pendent vertex"? Also is $G_1$ any graph?

Comment: It's from here. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.2281.pdf I guess pendent vertex is vertex with only one neighbour and that $G_{1}$ is any graph. About $P_{2}$ im not 100% sure.